# How do I prevent Eclipse (with pydev) from uncollapsing code?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I'm using Eclipse Kepler (4.3) (with pydev, in case that matters). If I collapse my code (using Ctrl-9 or the Source menu) and then selectively uncollapse only the part I'm working on, it works fine for a while. But at some point in the session, I'll notice that Eclipse has randomly (?) decided to uncollapse all the code. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a known "feature" of Eclipse? And is there any way to prevent it?

And in case there's no way to prevent this, I have a follow-up question: Is there any way to collapse just the code I have selected? I.e., can I select a set of functions and collapse them all at once rather than going through and collapsing them one at a time?